# Javascript Empty field validation - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have been researching for days and taken several example from here for a solution to validate a date fields to make sure it is not empty before moving to next page. but keeps getting cannot read property of undefined, and I have tried using Joomla build validate.js which will not work inside this custom component, and I am hoping for some help here to tackle this issue.

Here's the javascript

```
nextpage:function(){
var deliveryy=document.getElementsByName("customPlugin")[0].value;

    if(delivery == "" || delivery == null) {
    alert("filled out All Delivery Date & Time"); 
return false; } else { .........
```

Here's the onclick button

```
<button type="button" id="productbuilder_next" class="productbuilder_pagination pbbutton btn" onclick="productbuilder.nextpage();"> Next</button>
```

Here's the raw data of the field I am trying to validate that it is not empty

```
<input id="<?php echo $class.$rand ?>" class="required <?php echo $class ?>" required="true" type="text" value="" size="<?php echo $this->params->custom_size ?>" name="customPlugin[<?php echo $viewData[0]->virtuemart_customfield_id ?>][<?php echo $this->_name?>][comment]"><?php if($this->params->custom_populate_alternate_field){?>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="alternate<?php echo $rand?>" size="30">
```

Generated

```
<input id="vmcustom-datetime1930516000" class="required vmcustom-datetime hasDatepicker" required="true" type="text" value="" size="10" name="customPlugin[176][datetime][comment]">
```

Comment: You're looking for an element named `"customPlugin"`. You have an element named `"validDelivery customPlugin[176][datetime][comment]"`. Why would you expect that to match?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are generating the element id randomly?

Comment: @Paul Roub.  Thanks for the input.  No.  the validDelivery element was a mistake.

Comment: @Craicerjack.  The random id is generated by the custom component..

Comment: @user1833676 okay but does it have to be, can you remove the php and give it your own id?

Comment: @Craicerjack.  Thanks for the input.  I have not tried that, but I believe it may break the site, as this component is actually a virtuemart product generator. Validation works fine elsewhere within the site, but just not inside this components..  and I have hit a dead end with the developer.

Comment: @user1833676 ah okay. That would explain it. Is the input part of a form? Could you `.serialize()` it if it is? or if not use `.parent()` or `.closest()` to retrieve the value?

Comment: @Craicerjack  I don't believe it is part of a form, and I believe it would have been a lot easier if it is part of a form, but this routine is actually a steps routine to gather the various options before moving to the final form for submission.  I will give your suggested method a try and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a name that doesn't exist in the DOM. In this way, it'll throw this error when you access the property value.

Classes can be used here. Just add a class in your element and search for it in your function.

HTML:

```
<input id="vmcustom-datetime1930516000" class="required validDelivery vmcustom-datetime hasDatepicker" required="true" type="text" value="" size="10" name="customPlugin[176][datetime][comment]">
```

JS:

```
var validDelivery = document.getElementsByClassName("validDelivery")[0].value;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t1g7cfrb/1/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Name of your element is "validDelivery customPlugin[176][datetime][comment]"

And you want to handle it with getElementsByName("customPlugin"). It's incorrect.

You may for example add class customPlugin to element and handle it with getElementsByClassName("customPlugin")[0].

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I have tried setElementsByClass, ById, ByName, and all different method that have been suggested here that works.  But I have been getting cannot read property error, or when there are no error the page will return false even when the field is not empty or submitted even when empty.